# How to get car to start

Tags: starting, pontiac, grand-prix

I put new transmission in my 05 Pontiac Grand Prix GXP and car won’t start. It started up but i cut it off to put fluids in and now it won’t start anymore. Any ideas to fixing this??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You're going to have to help us a little more than what you have in your question. What is it doing? Does it turn over but won't start, or does it just do nothing when you turn the key? Does the dashboard light up when you turn the key to on? Are there any signs of life?